# ChatGPT Updated to gpt-3.5-turbo-1106, now my bot refuses to work

Tags: c#, discord, bots, chatgpt-api

I wrote a bot about a week ago to add ChatGPT to my Discord server.They updated their model, and ive attempted to get it to work using the new model.
I have tried to update it using the new model but the console window output when I run the ask command says:

```
Error communicating with OpenAI API. Status code: BadRequest
Error content: {
  "error": {
    "message": "'messages' is a required property",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
```

I have attempted to add messages = query, in requestBody but that says its null. I'm at a loss.

the code in question is below

```
public async Task<string> GetOpenAiResponse(string query)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {GptApiKey}");

        string prompt = $"User: {query}\nChatGPT:";

        // Create a JSON object for the request payload
        var requestBody = new
        {
            prompt = prompt,
            model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            max_tokens = 150
        };

        // Serialize the JSON object to a string
        var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

        // Use StringContent with the correct content type
        var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Parsing JSON to extract the response text
            var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(result);
            var choices = jsonResponse["choices"];
            var firstChoice = choices.FirstOrDefault();
            var text = firstChoice?["text"].ToString();

            return text ?? "Unable to parse OpenAI response.";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error communicating with OpenAI API. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Error content: {errorContent}");

            return "Error communicating with OpenAI API.";
        }
    }
}
```

Jons answer led me in the right direction!!!

The code below is correct and now working:

```
public async Task<string> GetOpenAiResponse(string query)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {GptApiKey}");

        string prompt = $"User: {query}\nChatGPT:";
        // Create message objects for the system and user messages
        var messages = new List<object>
    {
        new { role = "system", content = "You are a helpful assistant." },
        new { role = "user", content = query }
    };
        // Create a JSON object for the request payload
        var requestBody = new
        {
          
            model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages = messages,
            max_tokens = 150
        };

        // Serialize the JSON object to a string
        var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

        // Use StringContent with the correct content type
        var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Parsing JSON to extract the response text
            var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(result);
            var choices = jsonResponse["choices"];
            var firstChoice = choices.FirstOrDefault();
            var text = firstChoice["message"]["content"].ToString();

            return text ?? "Unable to parse OpenAI response.";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error communicating with OpenAI API. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Error content: {errorContent}");

            return "Error communicating with OpenAI API.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the error message sounds fairly descriptive. You're providing "prompt", "model" and "max_tokens" but not "messages". A quick search found https://benjamincrozat.com/gpt-35-turbo#make-your-first-request-to-gpt-35-turbo as a sort of tutorial...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you so much! That pointed me in the correct direction! I will post the working code in my OP as to help other users that may have the same issue!

Comment: Please don't post answers in the question. If you think your edit solves the question then please add the edit as an answer